# Kali LInux Internal Drive

Tags: hard-drive, terminal, kali-linux, liveusb

I am running Kali Linux 2016.1 live in my usb drive. I have to change my window admin password but internal drives of the system are showing in other device and I can't find it in terminal too.

when i run "Cd media/# ls" i only get my pendrive part.

Am I missing anything or there is another way ?

Comment: First, your command is invalid.
Try first changing the directory with `cd /media` and after that use `ls`. If you want to run those two in a single command, you have to add the `&&` operator, i.E. `cd /media && ls` or if you just want to list the entries, you can use `ls /media`. If there's a cdrom drive available, you should see the folder `cdrom`.

Comment: Thank you, I did the same thing but it was showing in "df -h" but did not show when i run the command. then I simply go to the other device and mount the "C drive" using option in right click. After that my drive started showing in /media && ls

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the mount point of the drive run " df -h" in terminal. It will list all the mounted devices and using that path you can access the location.

If the drive is not listing in the above command run " parted -l" where it will list the attached drives. you can check it via fdisk too.

Comment: Thank you, I did the same thing but it was showing in "df -h" but did not show when i run the command. then I simply go to the other device and mount the "C drive" using option in right click. After that my drive started showing in /media && ls